# Using output of a function as an input in a different function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, input

I'm trying to create a function in python (without numpy) that would imitate matrix multiplication in numpy. The program contains 2 functions. First function takes in 2 lists (l1 and l2) as  input and creates a dummy list (dummy). The second function does the matrix multiplication of the lists l1 and l2  and inputs the values in the dummy list (dummy). The issue is that in the final output, the column values are being added and repeated in each row. However, if I hard code the dummy list in the program, it is giving correct output. If I run the first function to create dummy list separately, I'm getting correct output. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Providing both the codes below. Please help.

#Following code is giving me erroneous result:

```
l1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
l2 = [[7,8,0],[9,10,5]]

def dummy_matrix(l1,l2):
    g = len(l1)
    h = len(l2[0])
    m = []
    p = []
    for j in range(h):
        p.append(0)
    for i in range(g):
        m.append(p)
    dummy = m
    return(dummy)

def mat_mul(l1,l2):
    f = dummy_matrix(l1,l2)
    for a in range(len(l1)):
        for b in range(len(l2[0])):
            for c in range(len(l2)):
                f[a][b] += l1[a][c]*l2[c][b]
    return(f)

mat_mul(l1,l2)
```

---

#Following code has hard coded dummy list and is giving correct output

```
l1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
l2 = [[7,8,0],[9,10,5]]
def dummy_matrix(l1,l2):
    g = len(l1)
    h = len(l2[0])
    m = []
    p = []
    for j in range(h):
        p.append(0)
    for i in range(g):
        m.append(p)
    dummy = m
    return(dummy)
def matrix_multi(l1,l2):
    f = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
    for a in range(len(l1)):
        for b in range(len(l2[0])):
            for c in range(len(l2)):
                f[a][b] += l1[a][c]*l2[c][b]
    return(f)
matrix_multi(l1,l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You create your dummy_matrix wrong. You first create a row called `p`, append some zeros to it and then you append **the same row** multiple times.

```
dm = dummy_matrix(l1, l2)

dm[1][2] = 1

print(dm)
```

You can notice that this will modify multiple rows, showing that they are in fact the same reference.
You need to create fresh list for each row:

```
    m = []
    for i in range(g):
        p = []
        for j in range(h):
            p.append(0)
        m.append(p)
```

Comment: Yes, I kept using p in each row in m and in the final function, the values kept getting added to p and used the same p everywhere. I rectified this code and my overall code is working fine now.